# How to find derivative of inverse function at a point where there is no clear path to get inverse function (calc1 lvl)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse, inverse-function

For a function $f\left(x\right)=tanx+3x^2$ at $a=0$, find $ \left(f^{-1}\right)'\:\left(a\right)$

Given context of a chapter [Derivatives of Inverse Functions](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/3-7-derivatives-of-inverse-functions)
I am trying to approach question with
$\left(f^{-1}\right)'\left(a\right)=\frac{1}{f'\left(f^{-1}\left(a\right)\right)}$

The solution requires $f^{-1}\left(a\right)$
Currently I don't have approach to find inverse $tanx+3x^2$ in general. Another idea that i had was to conditionally equate
$a=0=\:tanx+3x^2$
and solve for x, sadly I don't have approach to solve that as well.

I have feeling that i completely missed the point of the chapter, because i have similar struggles with most of the chapter's exercises, though I was lucky to be able to evaluate at least one of above so far.

I would be very thankful if your answer will help me see what I miss for the topic in general.

Source: Exercise 272 in openstax Calculus vol.1

Comment: You probably did miss the point of the chapter, which says that $f’(a) = \frac{1}{(f^{-1})’(f(a))}$ or more succinctly, $\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=a}= \frac{1}{dx/dy|_{y=f(a)}}$. In particular you don’t need to solve for the inverse function.

Comment: Could you please show how this should be applied to the exercise?

Comment: @shimey maybe try plugging in $\tan(x)+3x^2$ into the above??

Comment: The problem is ill-posed since there are infinitely many solutions to $\tan(x) +3x^2=0$. So, they should have indicated more specifically in the neighbourhood of which $x$ with $f(x) = 0=a$ the (local) inverse of $f$ is to be considered. Most probably they had in mind only $a=0$ and $x=0$.

Comment: @K.defaoite
In this case $f\left(a\right)'=1$ and $\:f\left(a\right)=0$ , therefore plugging in gives us
$\:1=\frac{1}{\left(f^{-1}\right)'\left(0\right)}$ That can be solved for the $\:\left(f^{-1}\right)'\left(a\right)=\:\left(f^{-1}\right)'\left(0\right)=1$.   
I guess I did not go there by myself because I did not expect $\left(f\left(a\right)\right)\:=\:a$  
If that would not be the case, how would we get solution?